# How to split text to match double quotes plus trailing text to dot?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-split

## How can I get a sentence that is in double quotes in which there is a dot that must be split?

**Example document like this:**

> “Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings,” said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen. “On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life.” he said.

**I want to get output like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>"Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings," said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen.
    [1] =>"On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life," he said.
 )
```

My code still explode by dots.

```
function sample($string)
{
    $data=array();
    $break=explode(".", $string);
    array_push($data, $break);

    print_r($data);
}
```

I'm still confused to split two delimiter about double quote and dot. because inside double quote there is a sentence that contain dot delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler pattern used by `preg_split()` followed by `preg_replace()` to fix the left and right double quotes up ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/napTp)):

```
$in = '“Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings,” said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen. “On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life.” he said.';

$out = preg_split('/ (?=“)/', $in, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
//$out = preg_match_all('/“.+?(?= “|$)/', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : null;

$find = '/[“”]/u';  // unicode flag is essential
$replace = '"';
$out = preg_replace($find, $replace, $out);  // replace curly quotes with standard double quotes

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '"Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings," said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen.',
  1 => '"On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life." he said.',
)
```

`preg_split()` matches the space followed by a `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTE).

The `preg_replace()` step requires a pattern with the `u` modifier to make sure the left and right double quotes in the character class are identified.  Using `'/“|”/'` means you can remove the `u` modifier, but it doubles the steps that the regex engine has to perform (for this case, my character class uses just 189 steps versus the piped characters using 372 steps).

Furthermore regarding the choice between `preg_split()` and `preg_match_all()`, the reason to go with `preg_split()` is because the objective is to merely split the string on the space that is followed by a `left double quote`.  `preg_match_all()` would be a more practical choice if the objective was to omit substrings not neighboring the delimiting space character.

Despite my logic, if you still want to use `preg_match_all()`, my `preg_split()` line can be replaced with:

```
$out = preg_match_all('/“.+?(?= “|$)/', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : null;
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: nice too.., but how we can print double quote in php?

Comment: oh.. I know my problem, just edit .htacces and add, specialcharacter `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .php`, thanks too @mickmackusa

Answer (score 2):

A perfect example for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
“[^“”]+”(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.\s*
# looks for strings in double quotes
# throws them away
# matches a dot literally, followed by whitespaces eventually
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
$regex = '~“[^“”]+”(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.\s*~';
$parts = preg_split($regex, $your_string_here);
```

This yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => “Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings,” said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen
    [1] => “On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life.”
)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VF9ONG/2) as well as [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/RqcawI).

Comment: can you tell me what the meaning of character `~` in your regex sintax? Cz I try to learn regex but I didn't find the character `~` in regex. Or can you give me reference to learn regex character?, thanks.

Comment: @Rachmad: These are delimiters such as `/` or `#` and needed on both sides of the regex string.

Comment: Oh..so If I change `~` to ~/~ its no problem? @Jan

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

**[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1eMPWv/4)** <sup>( *16 steps* )</sup>

**`“.[^”]+”(?:.[^“]+)?`**

- `“.[^”]+”` matches everything between **`“`** and **`”`**.
- `(?:.[^“]+)?` matches - *a possibility, this why there's the last* **`?`**- of everything that's not a starting **`“`**, **`?:`** means non-capturing group.

---

**PHP - [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rpc8-fubs):** - Hit "Run-F9" - [ *updated to replace* **`“`**, **`”`** *with* **`"`** ]

```php
<?php
    $str = '“Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings,” said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen. “On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life.”';

if(preg_match_all('/“.[^”]+”(?:.[^“]+)?/',$str, $matches)){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(preg_replace('[“|”]', '"', $matches[0]));
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

**output:**

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => "Chess helps us overcome difficulties and sufferings," said Unnikrishnan, taking my queen. 
>     [1] => "On a chess board you are fighting. as we are also fighting the hardships in our daily life."
> )
> ```